# CMD doesn't reconize javac -version command

Tags: java

I have a problem with my CMD, when i try to send command: **"javac - version" , ti returns an error "unreconized command"**
Like the image above, i tried to install java 1.8.121, but when i try to send command:**"echo %JAVA_HOME%" it returns  1.8.111**
Here you can see my variables
what can i do?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

move CMD to  %JAVA_HOME%\bin and execute javac, it should work, if yes than make ammedment in %JAVA_HOME% to bin folder

Answer (score 1):

The CMD shell must be restarted after installing/changing variables (Windows 7, probably true for later versions)!

`echo %JAVA_HOME%` is showing ...\jdk1.8.0_**111**

but your Windows settings are showing ...\jdk1.8.0_**121**

*Note*: `JAVA_HOME` is not used or required by Java itself, but since some tools/scripts use it, it is not wrong to set it.